# Android: How to use test project within main project

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to create project structure like this in Eclipse and use this with Maven:

```
MyProject/
      AndroidManifest.xml
      res/
          ... (resources for main application)
      src/
          ... (source code for main application) ...
      tests/
          AndroidManifest.xml
          res/
              ... (resources for tests)
          src/
              ... (source code for tests)
```

I read about this structure on android website. Here is this topic http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html

Can anybody helps me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses ant, not Maven, but may be of some help nevertheless:

http://www.paulbutcher.com/2010/09/android-library-project-with-tests-step-by-step/