# Android Unit Test within Project

Tags: android, android-build, android-testing

I'm trying to create an Android test project from within my main project. Exactly similar to this question [Android: How to use test project within main project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390732/android-how-to-use-test-project-within-main-project) (I'm trying to revive this because this question is outdated and I'm still unable to find an answer).

Basically I want to reproduce the way Android tests are.
They are literally just a /tests/ directory within the main project "see link for exact layout."

The main reason we want this is to be able reduce the amount of projects so we don't need 2 root folders for every project. (aka the test project and the real project).

I'm free to use whatever for the build since, but I'm assuming that nant is the way to go to automatically run tests.

Any help would be great, thanks.

EDIT: Note the problem with Eclipse is that is does not easily give this option (at least I haven't found it). You can navigate to the directory you want and create a /tests/ but it will also bring along another project attached and I ran into some linking issues doing that.)

Comment: Can you explain what the key limitation is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Creating a new Android test project from Eclipse ends up creating another entire project folder that I'm unable to figure out how to place in my main.

Comment: Yes, it is doable. So what is the problem you have when try to set up this project directory structure?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you can't just add a new source folder to your main project called "test" and start adding tests.

Comment: I was trying to use Eclipse and it wasn't giving that option. So I ended up having to use the $android tool. I suppose all my further problems are MAC build related. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't able to find this option in Eclipse.
However you can use the command line tools in order to build the test project where you want it.

```
~/android-main-project$ android create test-project -n tests -p ./tests -m ../
```

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you run into any other unit test problems. I had some pathing and linking issues at first, but got everything scripted and automated and working good.

Comment: Just ran into these...  New folders / files did not make it into any project configuration - so I'll have to figure out how I have to set up build paths.... You don't happen to have written a blog post about it, haven't you? ;)

Comment: No. I haven't written a public blog post. I'm actually having the same issue with setting the project properties on the tests project. It still works, but it makes coding my unit tests more difficult. I do plan on writing a good blog about Android unit tests once I can figure everything out. It'll be posted to mobile.cs.fsu.edu